# How to check NTP Setting on Vcenter

Tags: powershell, vmware, powershell-4.0, powercli, vcenter

I want to check NTP Setting on Vcenter is set to "running"
I am using the following cmdlet but it is returning back the IP addresses of the NTP servers.

```
Get-VMHostNtpServer -VMHost abc.com
```

How to check status is set to "running" or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Get-VMHostService` cmdlet](https://code.vmware.com/docs/6978/cmdlet-reference#/doc/Get-VMHostService.html) returns [`HostService`](https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/73d6de02-05fd-47cb-8f73-99d1b33aea17/850c6b63-eb82-4d9c-bfcf-79279b5e5637/doc/HostService.html) instances, which contain a `Running` property.

This example from [older `Get-VMHostService` documentation](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/windowstoolkit/wintk40u1/html/Get-VMHostService.html) shows a list of services (including `ntpd`) returned with the `Running` property:

```
C:\PS>Get-VMHostService -Refresh

Key Label Policy Running Required
--- ----- ------ ------- --------
ntpd NTP Daemon automatic False False
sshd SSH Server automatic True False
vmware-vpxa VMware VirtualCenter Agent automatic True False
```